# 2013 hyundai sante fe sport No Crank/No start

Tags: hyundai, catalytic-converter, no-crank-no-start, santa-fe

So my 2013 hyundai santefe started having a flashing check engine light and wouldn't accelerate past 2000rpms on my way to work one night. Pulled off the road into a parking garage. Please note at this time the engine did not sound any different then normal. Only new noise was a rapid fire fluttering sound coming from the middle of the car. I had it towed from the parking garage and to a mechanic shop. Where they told me my catalytic converter clogged and needed to be replaced. The shop then called and said repairs were done and they replaced the exhaust manifold along with the catalytic converter.  I went to go drive the car away and it didn't even make it off the lot after it made a horrible sound from the same location as the fluttering from before. Afterwords it did not crank or start. Any idea what could have went wrong? Any information would help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Since it is no longer starting, are you still seeing dash lights? Do the headlights still turn on? Did you take it back to the shop which did the work? Also, as per the cat, from the sounds of it, the shop did the right work. The reason they replaced the manifold is, the cat/manifold is integral. Ultimately right now, I'm wondering if they didn't get the battery lead tightened down after the work and this caused the vehicle to quit, but don't really know. If you haven't done so, take it back and tell them to fix their work.

Comment: Oh I wasn't even able to leave with the vehicle at all. It didn't even make it our of the parking lot. And as far as the dash is concerned I think the lights did come on. But it just didn't crank or start after trying to leave with it. I gave them a call back but they said they haven't had time to look at it but now it needs a whole new engine 

Comment: Is what they told me

Comment: Wow, that seems like a huge step from replacing a cat.

Comment: I know. When they sent me the diagnostics for the first repair  one of the codes was for an engine knock so im wondering if they misdiagnosed what was going on and they just killed my car

Comment: Engine knock is not synonymous with a bad engine. The knock which shows in engine codes as to do with pre-ignition. The knock which is the engine killer is when you get too much rod bearing "clearance" and it beats itself to death.

Comment: So could my starter just failed? Or something along those lines? Cause I'm really trying to wrap my head around what's going on since they still don't know anything and they're closed for the weekend.

Comment: Really, I think your best bet is to just wait for Monday and let them tell you what's going on. No sense in beating yourself around the head and shoulders. Nothing you can do about it until them.